# What is does the double brackets in JavaScript do?

Tags: javascript

I attach a function below. I am specifically confused about this line:

```
  , results = [[letters.shift()]]
```

What does the double bracket do in this case?

```
function stringPermutations(str) {
    let letters = str.split('')
      , results = [[letters.shift()]] 
    while (letters.length) {
        const currLetter = letters.shift()
        let tmpResults = []
        results.forEach(result => {
            let rIdx = 0
            while (rIdx <= result.length) {
                const tmp = [...result]
                tmp.splice(rIdx, 0, currLetter)
                tmpResults.push(tmp)
                rIdx++
            }
        })
        results = tmpResults
    }
    return results
      .map(letterArray => letterArray.join(''))
      .filter((el, idx, self) => (self.indexOf(el) === idx))
      .sort()
}
```

Comment: 2 dimensional array

Comment: Creates a 2D array with only one index.

Answer (score 2):

The outer [ ] creates an array. Inside this array, the inner [ ] creates a new array. So, the result is an array inside in array. The first (and only) element of the outer array is the inner array. The first (and only) element of the inner array is the result of the `shift()` call. Nicely formatted, it should become clearer:

```
[
    [
        letters.shift()
    ]
]
```

So, double brackets are no special construct in JavaScript.